# I'm creating image encryption and decryption using AES algorithm

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, encryption, caesar-cipher

When I enter a password to encrypt some image error appear.
Type error: String must be encoded before hashing
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p7KHB.png)

```
def pass_alert():
   messagebox.showinfo("Password Alert","Please enter a password.")

def enc_success(imagename):
   messagebox.showinfo("Success","Encrypted Image: " + imagename)

# image encrypt button event
def image_open():
    global file_path_e

    enc_pass = passg.get()
    if enc_pass == "":
        pass_alert()
    else:
        password = hashlib.sha256(enc_pass).digest()
        filename = filedialog.askopenfilename()
        file_path_e = os.path.dirname(filename)
        encrypt(filename,password)
```

Comment: Your passphrase is of string type but your hashlib.sha256 expects a byte array so you need a "StringToByte" encoder for conversion (e.g. password.encode("ascii"))

Comment: There is functionally no difference between "image encryption" and regular (binary) file encryption, unless you operate *within* the image format. To avoid confusion I'd just name the functions themselves "file encryption" or "data file encryption" to indicate the binary nature of it.

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/238704)

Answer (score 0):

Edit: There are two options.

Option 1:

Change this:

```
password = hashlib.sha256(enc_pass).digest()
```

to:

```
password = hashlib.sha256(enc_pass.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
```

Option 2:.

```
sha256_hash = hashlib.sha256()
message= enc_pass
sha256_hash.update(message.encode())
sha256_hash.hexdigest()
```

Comment: password = hashlib.sha256(enc_pass.encode('utf-8)).hexdigest() has worked but now raise ValueError("Incorrect AES key length (%d bytes)" % len(key)) ValueError: Incorrect AES key length (64 bytes) has appeared

Comment: If you change hexdigest to .digest()